# Match file names that are close, but not exact

Tags: r, string, filenames

I have multiple lists that have similar names except for the extensions. I was able to index them using a simple bracketed approach - `L1[1]` and `L2[2]` would be the correct match. However, I have many files to go through and a few of them don't match *index* number to *index* number.

In my example, there are a few missing files for one type. In my real-world first case, I have 122 *.json* files and 119 *.description* files. This throws off the index approach I was using. How can I match the correct list elements together in this case? I have tried a few different options using string matching and string splitting but I had no luck.

And just in case, yes, this meta-data is pulled using youtube-dl but I am the author of the videos.

The end goal is to have two variables `VTT` and `DESC` that I can use later in my R script. For example, VTT would equal the L1[2] and DESC would equal the L2[index where the titles are matched closely], e.g. the file name without extension or L2[3].

Both lists came from using `list.files()`; however, later in the program, I don't have full.names = TRUE and I work with just the file names themselves.

```
L1 <- c("c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/01 - Statistical Programming with R - Estimating f (Notation)/Statistical Programming with R - Estimating f (Notation).mp4.en.txt", 
+         "c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/02 - Statistical Programming - Expected Value/Statistical Programming - Expected Value.mp4.en.txt", 
+         "c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/03 - Linear Regression with R 01/Linear Regression with R 01.mp4.en.txt"
+ )

L2 <- c("c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/01 - Statistical Programming with R - Estimating f (Notation)/Statistical Programming with R - Estimating f (Notation).mp4.info.json", 
, 
"c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/03 - Linear Regression with R 01/Linear Regression with R 01.mp4.info.json",
"c:/ytdl//CradleToGraveR/Absolute Beginners Guide to Statistical Programming/02 - Statistical Programming - Expected Value/Statistical Programming - Expected Value.mp4.info.json"
)
```

Maybe my approach, in general, is wrong. I think my next approach will be to put list in a data.frame and strip the extension off. Then parse just the ending after the directory path. Finally, do a join or merge on the two data.frames? I feel like I am making this way more complicated than it should be.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to keep only that part of the string that exactly match with each other and compare them.

For the example shared if we keep only the file name without the complete path, strip off everything after `"."` and compare it works.

```
inds <- match(sub('\\..*', '', basename(L1)), sub('\\..*', '', basename(L2)))
inds
#[1] 1 3 2
```

You can create a dataframe with both the filenames in correct order

```
data.frame(L1 = L1, L2 = L2[inds])
```